# Select rows by ID with most matches

Tags: r, dataframe, aggregate

I have a data frame like this:

```
df <- data.frame(id = c(1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4),
                 torre = c("a","a","b","d","a","q","t","q","g","a","b","c"))
```

and I would like my code to select for each `id` the `torre` that repeats more, or the last `torre` for the `id` if there isnt one that repeats more than the other, so ill get a new data frame like this:

```
df2 <- data.frame(id = c(1,2,3,4), torre = c("a","a","q","c"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `aggregate`:

```
aggregate(torre ~ id, data=df,
  FUN=function(x) names(tail(sort(table(factor(x, levels=unique(x)))),1))
)
```

The full explanation for this function is a bit involved, but most of the job is done by the `FUN=` parameter. In this case we are making a function that get's the frequency counts for each `torre`, sorts them in increasing order, then get's the last one with `tail(, 1)` and takes the name of it. `aggregate()` function then applies this function separately for each id.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this using the `dplyr` package: group by `id` and `torre` to calculate the number of occurrences of each `torre`/`id` combination, then group by `id` only and select the last occurrence of `torre` that has the highest in-group frequency.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
group_by(id,torre) %>% 
mutate(n=n()) %>% 
group_by(id) %>% 
filter(n==max(n)) %>%
slice(n()) %>% 
select(-n)
     id torre
  <dbl> <chr>
1     1     a
2     2     a
3     3     q
4     4     c
```

Answer (score 1):

An approach with the [data.table](/questions/tagged/data.table) package:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, .N, by = .(id, torre)][order(N), .(torre = torre[.N]), by = id]
```

which gives:

> ```
>    id torre
> 1:  1     a
> 2:  2     a
> 3:  3     q
> 4:  4     c
> ```

---

And two possible [dplyr](/questions/tagged/dplyr) alternatives:

```
library(dplyr)

# option 1
df %>% 
  group_by(id, torre) %>% 
  mutate(n = n()) %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  mutate(f = rank(n, ties.method = "first")) %>% 
  filter(f == max(f)) %>% 
  select(-n, -f)

# option 2
df %>% 
  group_by(id, torre) %>% 
  mutate(n = n()) %>% 
  distinct() %>% 
  arrange(n) %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  slice(n()) %>% 
  select(-n)
```

Answer (score 1):

Yet another `dplyr` solution, this time using `add_count()` instead of `mutate()`:

```
df %>%
  add_count(id, torre) %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  filter(n == max(n)) %>% 
  slice(n()) %>% 
  select(-n)

# A tibble: 4 x 2
# Groups:   id [4]
     id torre
  <dbl> <fct>
1    1. a    
2    2. a    
3    3. q    
4    4. c
```